# Selenium + Java = FindElements (list) and check if some of them contains a specific text

Tags: java, selenium

My question:

Let suppose I have a page with the products I bought. In this page I need to verify if one of these products added contains the same name that I got in a previous step and put into a var (`String firstProductName`).

So I notice the cssLocator `.name` is the locator for all these products' names. If I had only one product bought, I would just find it by this locator and use `getText()` to verify if contains the same name that I have stored in the var `firstProductName`.

The problem is: Sometimes I have only one product, sometimes I have more than one.

I need to:

1. Access this page, find all elements with the `.name` locator.
2. Then I need to check one by one seeing if through the `getText()` method the text found contains my string `firstProductName`
3. If at least one have the name equals to this String, my test is ok. If not, the test fails.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
List<WebElement> allProducts = select.findElements(By.cssSelector("{not quite clear what your selector is, but it includes "name"}"));
for (WebElement product: allProducts) {
    if(product.getText().equals(firstProductName)) 
        return; // or break or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap this all up in a function as below.

```
/**
 * Determines if the supplied product name is found on the page
 * 
 * @param productName
 *            the product name to be searched for
 * @return true if the product name is found, false otherwise
 */
public boolean foundProduct(String productName)
{
    List<WebElement> products = driver.findElements(By.className("name"));
    for (WebElement product : products)
    {
        if (product.getText().trim().equals(productName))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then in your test code you would do something like

```
assertTrue(foundProduct("some product name"));
```

but I don't know if you are using TestNG, etc. Basically the test passes if `true` is returned or fails if `false` is returned.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did it and worked properly..!

=D

Comment: Glad to hear it. If it helped you, please accept it as the answer so that the question gets marked as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For Java 8 and above try this solution

```
public boolean productsContainsProvidedProduct(String product) {

 List<WebElement> products = driver.findElements(By.xpath("your_xpath_to_list_of_elements"));  
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(products));
 return products.stream().anyMatch(e -> e.getText().trim().contains(product));
}
```